# How to detect a series of characters in a string?

Tags: javascript

For example, I have a string:

```
"This is the ### example"
```

I would like to substring the `###` out of the above string?

The number of Hash keys may vary, so I would like to find out and replace the `###` pattern with, say, `001` for example.

Can anybody help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to capture multiple `#` characters, then you'll need regular expressions:

```
var myString = "This is #### the example";
var result = myString.replace(/#+/g, '');
```

If you want to remove the space too, you can use the regex `/#+\s|\s#+|#+/`.

Comment: Great! Thanks a lot. How can I count the length of that Hash key seri? which is 4 in this case?

Comment: Regex classes usually allow you to find the regex matches in your string and give them back to you as a string array. You can then count the length of the string.

Comment: Like this, http://www.learn-javascript-tutorial.com/RegularExpressions.cfm, if you new up a RegExp class and run the exec method you will receive a string array as the resulting match or matches.

Answer (score 3):

You can also do a replace. I am familiar with the C# version of this,

```
string stringValue = "Thia is the ### example";
stringValue.Replace("###", "");
```

This would remove ### completely from the above string. Again you would have to know the exact string.

In JavaScript, it's similar - [`.replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) (with a lowercase `r`) is used. So:

```
var stringValue = "This is the ### example";
var replacedValue = stringValue.replace('###', '');
```

Comment: The number of # keys vary, it may be 1, or may be 10 characters, not just 3. Thanks anyway :)

Comment: Just random, but you could do the replace in a loop, and just replace '#' with ' ' until there are no more hashes. But the regex solution is better I would agree in your case.

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to investigate either "[Regular Expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions)" for this, or, if you know the precise position and length of the characters you are interested in, you can simply use String's [`.substring`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring) method.

Answer (score 0):

If the rest of the string is known, just get the part that you need:

```
var example = str.substr(12, str.length - 20);
```

Comment: That's, um, C# that doesn't compile.

Comment: @minitech: It was, I edited it when I saw that the question was about Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

The javascript match method will return an array of substrings matching a regular expression. You can use this to determine the number of matching characters to be replaced. Assuming you want to replace each octothorpe with a random digit, you could use code like this:

```
var exampleStr = "This is the ### example";
var swapThese = exampleStr.match(/#/g);
if (swapThese) {
    for (var i=0;i<swapThese.length;i++) {
        var swapThis = new RegExp(swapThese[i]);
        exampleStr = exampleStr.replace(swapThis,Math.floor(Math.random()*9));
    }
}
alert(exampleStr); // or whatever you want to do with it
```

Note that the code only loops the length of the array if it's present: `if (swapThese) {`

This check is necessary because if the match method finds no matches, it returns null rather than an empty array. Trying to iterate through null value will break.